# erro [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

Por algum motivo que ainda não consegui identificar o python não está conseguindo localizar o caminho.

```
for profile in sorted(profile_ids):
    path = '/FileStore/tables/'
    filename = 'google_analytics_data_%s_1.csv'
    with open(path + filename % profile.lower(), 'wt') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        if __name__ == '__main__': main(sys.argv)
    print("Profile done. Next profile...")
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/FileStore/tables/google_analytics_data_

Comment: Se não encontrou é porque de fato não existe. Vi que o seu `path` inicia com uma barra, indicando que o caminho é absoluto em relação à raiz do sistema. Deveria ser isso mesmo? Está parecendo que você pretendia acessar um caminho relativo.

Comment: entendi que devia começar com / por se tratar de um caminha DBFS e mesmo tirando a / o erro persiste

Comment: Substitui `path = '/FileStore/tables/'` por `path =f'/FileStore/tables/'`.

Comment: @Solkarped, resolveu o problema, obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Só uma dica: evite usar `+` para montar seu path, para paths existe `os.path.join()`